# SSRS Subreports into main reports

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have main report with a data set and two different sub reports .All these reports have an Common id between. Can someone post how I can get these sub reports into the main report linking through the common id .

I have tried different videos from YouTube by adding a parameter within the sub report but I am keep getting errors

Comment: What error are you getting? what have you done so far?

Comment: Show us! Error Message.

Comment: I had a parameter created in the sub report and dragged and dropped the sub report into the main report , but  am getting an error that the sub report cant be shown